# My World_Time DataBase design/ORM

Tags: sql, orm, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relation

I have a Database design I would like to get some feedback/help with.

I have 3 different entities: `Cities`, `TimeZones`, `Rules`.

- a `City` is associated with 1 and only 1 `TimeZone` (not < 1, not > 1: just 1)
- a `TimeZone` may be associated with many `Cities` (Not sure about the minimum number of cities).
- a `TimeZone` has exactly 2 `Rules` (DST and ST).
- each `Rule` may be associated with many different `TimeZones`

I designed my Tables using the ORM Designer just to help me visualize:

[image: My Database ORM]

In this ORM, there is:

- a one to many relationship between the parent `TimeZones` and child `Cities`
- a one to many relationship between the parent `TimeZones` and child `TimeZoneRule`
- a one to many relationship between the parent `Rule` and child `TimeZoneRule`

Now for my questions:

- Will this many to many junction table work?
- How will I know what `Rule` belongs with what `TimeZone`? I have the `TimeZone.RuleName` property  to fetch the `Rule` for a `TimeZone` but what If I wanted to go backwards, say find all of the `TimeZones` that a rule applies to?
- How do I get around using a string (`RuleName`) to find the TimeZone's `Rule` since a `TimeZone` has 2 rules (with the same name but different/unique ID's).
- How do I populate this junction table with the right ID's/rows?
- I know `City` has a `TimeZoneId` that I added the actual values for, and I can use this `TimeZoneId` to find the `TimeZone` a `City` belongs in, but how can I find all of the `Cities` a `TimeZone` contains?

Below I pasted the TSQL code I wrote to create these tables, the only thing I don't have are the associations as I have never made associations in TSQL (clearly).

```
            USE World_Time

            IF OBJECT_ID('timezones', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE timezones;
            IF OBJECT_ID('rules', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE rules;
            IF OBJECT_ID('leaps', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE leaps;
            IF OBJECT_ID('cities', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE cities;
            IF OBJECT_ID('timezone_rule', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE timezone_rule;

            CREATE TABLE timezones
            (
                [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                [name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                [bias] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [rule_name] VARCHAR(10),
                [tz_abreviation] VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
                [country_code] CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                [country_name] VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
                [comments] VARCHAR(100),
                [coordinates] VARCHAR(20),
                [version] ROWVERSION
            );

            CREATE TABLE rules
            (
                [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                [name] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                [bias] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [start_year] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [end_year] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [month] TINYINT NOT NULL,
                [date] VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
                [time] TIME(0) NOT NULL,
                [time_type] CHAR(1),
                [letter] CHAR(1),
                [version] ROWVERSION
            );

            CREATE TABLE leaps
            (
                [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                [year] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [month] VARCHAR(3),
                [day] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                [time] TIME(0) NOT NULL,
                [correction] VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                [rs] VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                [version] ROWVERSION
            );

            CREATE TABLE cities
            (
                [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                [name] VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                [ascii_name] VARCHAR(200),
                [alternate_names] VARCHAR(5000),
                [latitude] FLOAT(24),
                [longitude] FLOAT(24),
                [feature_class] CHAR(1),
                [feature_code] VARCHAR(10),
                [country_code] CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                [country_code2] VARCHAR(60),
                [population] BIGINT,
                [elevation] INT,
                [modification_date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
                [admin1code] VARCHAR(20),
                [admin2code] VARCHAR(80),
                [admin3code] VARCHAR(20),
                [admin4code] VARCHAR(20),
                [gtopo30] INT,
                [timezone_id] INT NOT NULL,
                [timezone_name] VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
                [version] ROWVERSION
            );

            CREATE TABLE timezone_rule
            (
                [timezone_id] INT NOT NULL,
                [rule_id] INT NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (timezone_id, rule_id),
                [version] ROWVERSION
            );

            -- Is this how I would populate the junction table?
            --INSERT INTO timezone_rule
            --  (timezone_id)
            --SELECT id
            --FROM timezones;
            --INSERT INTO timezone_rule
            --  (rule_id)
            --SELECT id
            --FROM rules;
```

I apologize for the monstruous post I just have been trying to do this for months and I got fed up with Binging/googling for hours every day :P
Thanks for taking the time to read, I really appreciate it/

-Francisco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll skip over the part about whether you really need/should be doing this instead of using standard libraries and just address the question of a timezone mapping to two rules.

`Timezone` has a `RuleId`. It could have two `RuleId`s:

- DstRuleId
- StRuleId

For example:

```
        CREATE TABLE timezones
        (
            [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            [name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            [bias] SMALLINT NOT NULL,

            [dst_rule_id] INT,
            [st_rule_id]  INT,

            [tz_abreviation] VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
            [country_code] CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
            [country_name] VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
            [comments] VARCHAR(100),
            [coordinates] VARCHAR(20),
            [version] ROWVERSION
        );
```

That would be simplest. For greater flexibility, and to go down the more relational route, a `RuleType` table could be introduced which starts with only two entries:

- DST
- ST

This would allow the ability to expand the rules in the future. But then you would need a mapping from the `Rule` table to the `RuleType` table and the `TimeZoneRule` table would refer to these mappings. It is easier to use a DstRuleId and an StRuleId if there is high confidence this is not going to change.

- Find all of the TimeZones that a rule applies to?

  `SELECT timezoneid FROM TimeZoneRule WHERE RuleId = ?`
- How do I get around using a string (RuleName) to find the TimeZone's Rule since a TimeZone has 2 rules (with the same name but different/unique ID's).

  *implicit if you have the two columns in TimeZoneRule*
- How do I populate this junction table with the right ID's/rows?

  `INSERT INTO timezone_rule(timezone_id, rule_id) VALUES (?, ?)`
- I know City has a TimeZoneId that I added the actual values for, and I can use this TimeZoneId to find the TimeZone a City belongs in, but how can I find all of the Cities a TimeZone contains?

  `SELECT id FROM city WHERE timezone_id = ?`

Comment: The reason I am not using standard libraries is because this will be a local database on a Windows Phone Application, which unfortunately, does not contain the libraries.